# IIS 10 Rewrite with Parameters

Tags: windows, redirect, iis, parameters, web-config

i am trying to solve a IIS redirect (http + https) with parameters.

Source-URL: subdomain.example.com

Target-URL: https://target.com/com/en/products-z/xxx/yyy/wow-fan.html?utm_source=oldvanity&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=oldvanity

I used the following web.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="(.*)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://target.com/com/en/products-z/xxx/yyy/wow-fan.html?utm_source=oldvanity&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=oldvanity" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                </rules>
            </rewrite>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://target.com/com/en/products-z/xxx/yyy/wow-fan.html?utm_source=oldvanity&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=oldvanity" exactDestination="true" childOnly="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
        </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

With this web.config an access is not possible and a internal Server error occurs.

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Length: 1192
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
```

If i do edit the target in web.config to:
Target-URL: https://target.com/com/en/products-z/xxx/yyy/wow-fan.html?utm_source=oldvanity

it works fine.

My web.config does not work with the parameters "&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=oldvanity" in the Targetlink.

I tried $Q$A at the end of in the targetlink as well but did not work.

Any help is highly appreciated. Does anybody know how Target with & in it can be redirected correctly?

Thank you very much and best regards
Max

Comment: Use FRT to learn who gave you that 500 first, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules Only then you get something to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you again for your help!

I have now combined our web.config and it works! :D
Also HSTS Support has been added

@Jalpa - you are great thank you very very much for your help!
@Lex Ki - thank you as well - how to read out Server errors is an important point i have ignored in Windows/ IIS so far ;)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="(.*)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://target.com/com/en/products-z/xxx/yyy/wow-fan.html?utm_source=oldvanity&amp;utm_medium=redirect&amp;utm_campaign=oldvanity" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                </rules>
                    <outboundRules>
                <rule name="Add Strict-Transport-Security when HTTPS" enabled="true">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Strict_Transport_Security"
                        pattern=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" />
                </rule>
            </outboundRules>
            </rewrite>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://target.com/com/en/products-z/xxx/yyy/wow-fan.html?utm_source=oldvanity&amp;utm_medium=redirect&amp;utm_campaign=oldvanity" exactDestination="true" childOnly="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
        </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

All the best

Answer (score 0):

you could try this below rule:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="subdomain.example.com" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://target.com/com/en/products-z/xxx/yyy/wow-fan.html?utm_source=oldvanity&amp;utm_medium=redirect&amp;utm_campaign=oldvanity" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
Unfortunately this doesnt worked and a Internal error occured. 
Even if tried it without the whole targeturl (https://target.com/com/en/products-z/xxx/yyy/wow-fan.html?utm_source=oldvanity) an error occured (403 Forbidden)

I try to check out why the error exist as Lex Ki wrote

But anyway thank you very much! 
Best regards

Comment: here is the output from my side [image](https://imgur.com/a/8vV720S) , if it is not working you can try the failed request tracing and share the log with us